# How can we implement Windows desktop application integrate with SignalR based on ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

Our base project implemented with ASP.NET Boilerplate, ASP.NET MVC, AngularJS.
We have desktop application that communicate with Web API project.
How we can use SignalR in our desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

In windows desktop framework 4.8 add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client` from NuGet.

Create a Hub connection method

Map receive event `hubConnection.On`

Start with `StartAsync()`

```
HubConnection hubConnection;
string _messageRecived;

async Task InizializzaConnectioTuBlazorHub()
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/chathub")
   .Build();

    hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
    {
        _messageRecived = message;
        textBox1.Text= _messageRecived;
    });

    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

After that, send a message.

```
async Task Send()
{
    if (hubConnection != null)
    {
        await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", "Desktop: Ciao");
    }
}
```

See [Blazor Communicates with Win Desktop App through SignalR](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5327741/Blazor-Communicates-with-Win-Desktop-App-through-S) in the link I'v made a tips to communicate between Blazor and Windows form.